# Convert set of images to a single video file in android

Tags: android, image, video

I have a set of images with me, I wish to run them through a loop , and save it as a video file in sdcard. Is there any default utility in android which I can use. ? Any libraries that can fulfill my requirement. ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13643046/how-to-convert-images-into-video-in-android-using-javacv

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13643046/how-to-convert-images-into-video-in-android-using-javacv


Visit the above link ...

Comment: @Shishir Shetty ... did you find any solution?

Comment: @Androiddev I ended up using https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/02/xuggler-tutorial-frames-capture-video.html . . Please note this was like 5 years ago.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a library for creating these. There are some post here about that:

[Java Package to create video](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2175210/looking-for-a-java-package-to-create-video)

[Video Creation with Xuggler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9175543/video-creation-from-a-set-of-images-with-xuggler)

**Tutorial :**

[Tutorial To create Video from Xuggler](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/02/xuggler-tutorial-frames-capture-video.html)

Answer (score 0):

There is no built in `Android` library that supports this functionality. [This SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3688993/encode-a-series-of-images-into-a-video) suggest the use of the `ffmpeg` written in C/C++ via a Java port or using the `Android NDK`.

Answer (score 0):

Used Java `javacpp.jar` and `javacv.jar` in your android project to create series of Images to Video

Below Code Use to create video

```
recorder = new FFmpegFrameRecorder("Videofilename", 480, 480);

try {
    recorder.setVideoCodec(13);
    recorder.setFrameRate(0.4d);
    recorder.setPixelFormat(0);
    recorder.setVideoQuality(1.0d);
    recorder.setVideoBitrate(4000);

    startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    recorder.start();

    int time = Integer.parseInt(params[0]);
    resp = "Slept for " + time + " milliseconds";

    for (int i = 0; i < iplimage.length; i++) {
        long t = 1000 * (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime);
        if (t < recorder.getTimestamp()) {
            t = recorder.getTimestamp() + 1000;
        }
        recorder.setTimestamp(t);
        recorder.record(iplimage[i]);
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: where are the jar file ? No links.

Answer (score -2):

An object used to create frame-by-frame animations, defined by a series of Drawable objects, which can be used as a View object's background.

The simplest way to create a frame-by-frame animation is to define the animation in an XML file, placed in the res/drawable/ folder, and set it as the background to a View object. Then, call start() to run the animation.

An AnimationDrawable defined in XML consists of a single element, and a series of nested tags. Each item defines a frame of the animation. See the example below.

spin_animation.xml file in res/drawable/ folder:

```
<!-- Animation frames are wheel0.png -- wheel5.png files inside the
 res/drawable/ folder -->
 <animation-list android:id="@+id/selected" android:oneshot="false">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/wheel0" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/wheel1" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/wheel2" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/wheel3" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/wheel4" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/wheel5" android:duration="50" />
 </animation-list>
```

Here is the code to load and play this animation.

```
 // Load the ImageView that will host the animation and
 // set its background to our AnimationDrawable XML resource.
 ImageView img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.spinning_wheel_image);
 img.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.spin_animation);

 // Get the background, which has been compiled to an AnimationDrawable object.
 AnimationDrawable frameAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) img.getBackground();

 // Start the animation (looped playback by default).
 frameAnimation.start();
```

Comment: Thanks @Aakash but how are you planning to save it as a video file ?